# Where should I perform File IO workload in PortAudio if not in the callbacks

Tags: portaudio

I am using PortAudio to record multichannel audio data. I want to save the data from each channel as a separate file. Therefore, I have to do some File IO work somewhere in the program. Since the document recommend not doing any IO work in the callback function since they are called in a high frequency.

Then, what is the right way to perform the IO work ?  Should I start another thread?

Thanks in advance for your time on reading my post!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1) Have a buffer for each channel. These buffers will be your storage buffers and not the ones you have in the callback. I'd suggest declarinng these buffers in your `paData` structures. You'll have to decide the buffer length according to how much storage you have or time limit.

2) When you stop the recording, have it call a method which does your file IO work.

3) Use the buffers you had from step 1 and write to the file.

4) Repeat

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found something which shares the same spirit as what you said.  There is a data structure called RingBuffer, which handle writing and reading with multiple threads in parallel. In the call back function, I should write into the ring buffer while using a separate thread to read the ring buffer and write to a file.

Comment: Ah yes! circular buffers are the way to go. I would read the circular buffers in bulks... so if you had 2048 sample-size array, I'd read it every 1024 samples or something. That way you aren't wasting time reading / recording every sample